# Netlogo - how to determine a turtle intensity turn ? (heading)

Tags: netlogo

I've encountered some difficulties with Netlogo, and hope I can have some ideas here.

The problem is : a turtle is on a patch, and it can move-to one of neighbors. How it is possible to take into account, with a code, the intensity of the potentiel turn ?

The idea is that the patch in front of the turtle correspond to an intensity of 0. Those on the sides to 1, 2, 3 until 4. The last one (intensity of 4) is the patch corresponding to a 180° turn.

A first idea was to create "targets" of the 8 neighbors with "patch-right-and-ahead [heading] [distance] " and gave the intensity depending on the heading.

For instance :

```
let target45-1 **patch-right-and-ahead** 45 1
  let target180-1 **patch-right-and-ahead** 180 1
```

[.....]

```
 ask target180-1 [set turn_Intensity 4]
```

But the problem is that patch-right-and-ahead [heading] [distance], with the 8 heading 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315 and a distance of 1 **doesn't take into account all the 8 neighbors depending on the heading of the turtles, because the diagonals patches have their centers longer than a distance 1**. Then it happens than patch-right-and-ahead 45 1  and  patch-right-and-ahead 90-1 can **consider a same patch**. Some patches of the 8 neighbors are then forgotten.

Another idea was then to use the agentset **neighbors**, which never forget any neighbor patch. But how to determine the value of the potential turn the turtle would do if it moves towards a patch?

I tried this code, which seems to work, but I'm searching for any best ideas.

[picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWX3T.png)

```
to test

ask turtles [
    
 let InitialHeading heading
 set List_Neighbors sort neighbors  ; "sort neighbors" gave a list, which enable the use of foreach (which doesn't like agentset but prefer list)
 
set Listetest []
    
foreach List_Neighbors  [
neighbor-i  -> face neighbor-i   ; the turtle will face each neighbors
    
let AngleTurn abs (subtract-headings InitialHeading heading)  ;give an angle beetween 0 and 180°
    
ask neighbor-i [set angletest AngleTurn ]  ; angletest is a patch-own variable
    
set Listetest lput AngleTurn Listetest    ; the goal is having a list of all the patches' angletest values
    ]
    
set Listetest sort Listetest     ; "sort" will order the list in ascending order 
    
ask neighbors [
   if angletest = max Listetest [set plabel 4]  ;we choose that the maximum value correspond to a 4
   if angletest = min Listetest [set plabel 0]  ; we choose that theminimum value correspond to a 0 (the turtle will go almost straight)
    
   if (position angletest Listetest = 1) or (position angletest Listetest = 2) [set plabel 1] ; the other 6 values are distributed with 3 values 
                                                                                              ;of intensity  x 2 value in the list
    
   if (position angletest Listetest = 3) or (position angletest Listetest = 4) [set plabel 2]
   if (position angletest Listetest = 5) or (position angletest Listetest = 6) [set plabel 3]
           ]
]
end
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: re "how to determine the value of the potential turn the turtle would do if it moves towards a patch", you could combine `towards` with `subtract-headings`. I'm not positive there isn't a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

`to reproduce-killer if random-float 100 < killer-reproduce AND count killer < Numero_Killer[  ; throw "dice" to see if you will reproduce set sk (sk / 2)                ; divide energy between parent and offspring hatch 1 [ rt random-float 360 fd 1 ]   ; hatch an offspring and move it forward 1 step ] end`

You can use a random float connect to a slider in the GUI to emulate the probability of a situation (in this code I wanted to control the birth probability of my agent ). Set the slider from 0 to 100 and see it like 0% of probability to 100%.